# KVM and rdtsc latency

Tags: x86, kvm

As part of debugging our guest VM, we use rdtsc quite extensively to monitor the amount of time (ok, clock cycles) being used. The question was raised that this was expensive in itself as rdtsc yields a VM exit. I can think of no lower level means of finding out how much clock time or equivalent has elapsed. Is there any other solution ? Is this really expensive ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessary for every rdtsc to result in VM Exit, atleast not on Intel CPU's. ASAIK, the Virtual Machine Control Structure(VMCS) has a bit which dictates whether every RDTSC should cause a VM-Exit. Check "Definitions of Primary Processor-Based VM-Execution Controls – BIT 12" (Table 21-6) of [Intel Architecture Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253669.pdf)

There is a [nifty script(vmxcap.py)](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob_plain;f=scripts/kvm/vmxcap) which can be used to quickly dump this info. For example, on my machine where RDTSC does not incur VM-Exit, I get the below:

```
[root@XYZ ~]# ./vmxcap.py  | grep -i rdtsc
RDTSC exiting                            no
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: V. interesting - I'm trying to grok how this is used now - seems for nested kvm (CPU_BASED_RDTSC_EXITING) if the cpu does not have this feature then the outer VM does not need to do a VM exit for the inner VM from L2 to L1.  If I'm following this correctly.

Comment: If the value for `RDTSC exiting` is `yes`, what does that mean? What exactly does this file show?